# unable to deploying react app under subdirectory on nginx running in docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I am unable to deploy my react app under a sub directory on nginx running in docker container.

Below are the details

1. React app basename setting BrowserRouter basename='/myreactapp'
2. Package.json has "homepage": "/myreactapp"
3. nginx.conf

   ```
   server {

       server_name localhost;

       index index.html;

       error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

       access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

       root /usr/share/nginx/html;

       location /myreactapp {

           try_files $uri $uri/ /myreactapp/index.html;

       }

   }
   ```
4. Docker file

   ```
   FROM nginx:1.14.1
   COPY /build /usr/share/nginx/html
   COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
   EXPOSE 80
   CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
   ```
5. With this it still servers the app from '/' root location but not 
   /myreactapp

Comment: Location key is the “public path”, change it to “/“

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work. I it still servers the page from localhost:<port>/ and not from localhost:<port>/myreactapp/

Answer (score 1):

In your Dockerfile, replace this line:

```
COPY /build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

with this:

```
COPY /build /usr/share/nginx/html/myreactapp
```

Answer (score -1):

For me worked following this two articles

https://medium.com/@svinkle/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-a-subdirectory-f694d46427c1

https://medium.com/@darshanpawar/nginx-configuration-changes-after-you-deploy-react-application-in-a-sub-directory-f5b36453fed1

My nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /myreactapp {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /myreactapp/index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

My Dockerfile

```
# replace nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# copy files from build stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html/myreactappenter
```

Comment: HI, please add an explanation how/why your code fixes the issue to your answer so that you can help other people understand the issue rather then just fix it by copy + paste.